# Jquery ajax Rest Service Call : Typo Error Access is denied

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf, rest

I am calling WCF Rest Service from Jquery as shown below.
In my WCF Rest Service Security Mode is Transport.
This Below code returns me "Access is denied" error.

```
<script type ="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function GetRestData() {
            var Guid = $('#txtUserGuid').val();
            var CountryCode = $('#txtCountryCode').val();
            var FromDate = $('#txtFromDate').val();
            var ToDate = $('#txtToDate').val();
            jQuery.support.cors = true;         

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost/OrderList/OrderListService.svc/RestService/GetOrderList?request=" + Guid + ";" + CountryCode + ";" + FromDate + ";" + ToDate,
                type: "GET",
                cache:false,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
                    $('#result').html('JSON Greetings: ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + ' ' + textStatus + '  ' + errorThrown);
                    $('#result').innerHTML = "Unavailable";
                }
            });           
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: dont use https://localhost/ . just pass the relative url.  `OrderList/OrderListService.svc/RestService/GetOrderList?request=`

Comment: @Ravi : How it will find the service deployed in the IIS with relative url ?

Comment: it will use the current Domain. `//OrderList/OrderListService.svc/RestService/GetOrderList?request=`

Comment: @Ravi : Exception : The Service does not exist...

Comment: Anybody can help out there ?

Comment: Are you making Cross domain call , in that case you may consider using JSONP technique. Also check your cross domain policy xml file which should be in the root of your web app. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Set security mode to "none" and try if you still get error then there is some other problem

Comment: @AjayKelkar : For None it is working i want to make it work "https"

Comment: Then you should open the page the script is on through `https` too.

Comment: @dualed : What do you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

did your localhost hold any security code?
If so, then you would got the access error everytime try to access.
Try to give the security in the code, or remove the security code.

Comment: What do you mean by Security Code ? How i can check that ?

Comment: check from your control panel of your host that hold /localhost/Your_Web_Site. check that who can access that request only. That is the security at first. check that first